# how to find contacts who have paid for their membership?

Tags: civimember, search, smartgroups, payment

Civi 5.15.1, WP 5.3.2

My organization manually enters all memberships and membership payments using the Civi UI (we don't expose this functionality on our website). I need to create a smart group of contacts for whom the membership record has been created AND the Member Dues payment is Completed. However, I can't find any payment-related fields in the Advanced Search form used to add contacts to a smart group, except for Pay Later, which does not appear on the New Membership form anyway (perhaps we disabled it in some settings somewhere).

I've also tried searching for the Member Dues financial type, the Completed payment status, any payment type, and any date received, using Find Contribution, Search Builder, the Custom Searches, and all the available Contribution and Membership reports. Either no results return or those fields are empty.

The [Civi documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/defining-memberships/#membership-status-rules) implies that any membership that has not been paid for is in Pending status, so maybe I could search for membership statuses that are not that, or even create a new one to do the trick? Alas no -- any new membership we create starts out in Current status (we disabled New), I believe because we're entering it manually. And the membership status rules are based solely on Member Since and start/end date, not payment status. Nor is the Pending rule editable.

So, is there any way to find payments the way we can find contacts, memberships, events, contributions, etc? If not, are my only options to figure out how to get Pay Later on the membership form, or to create a custom field that essentially duplicates payment status? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Advance search to get the contacts that have membership and have paid for their membership.

1. Navigate to CiviCRM >> Search >> Advance search
2. Expand Contribution accordion
3. Select Contribution status to Completed and other filters if required
4. Expand Membership accordion
5. Select 'Membership is a Test?' to No and other filters if required
6. Hit Search.

The result should only list contact having membership with its payment.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: The Contribution accordion didn't appear on the Advanced Search page, so I enabled it from Display Preferences. Now I can create the required smart group—thanks! There was another problem, though: no one had recorded any payments for the membership type I was looking at, which explains why none of the other methods I tried had worked. I should've checked that first. But thanks again!